# Displaying date format dd/mm/yy in Lightning component side

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How to display date in dd/mm/yy format.

```
  <ui:outputDate value="{!v.CreatedDate }"
```

output:17-jan-2018

How to display date in following format:

output:17-01-2018

Answer (score -3):

lightning:formattedDateTime i tried and it worked fine for me.

 if you remove the timezone tag it will respect the user locale settings.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if you **[edit]** its content to include a complete sample of what your markup looked like.

Comment: <lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!v.date}" timeZone="Europe/Berlin" year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric"/>

Comment: @bksfdc Please add content as an **edit**, as Adrian said, rather than a comment.

Comment: Indeed you should **[edit]** your post to include any code. That's not what comments are for.